# How to deploy to vercel static files? only html, css and js

Tags: javascript, html, static, vercel

I found a solution - read my first answer.

I am trying to deploy a repository from my github.

The project contains some static files:

```
├─js
│　├─form.js
│　├─logic.js
│　└─anotherFile.js
├─index.html
└─styles.css
```

After I deploy the project (without choosing framework - choosing "other") I get 404 (`Failed to load resource`) when I enter the project from the new domain.

Just to mention, the project works fine locally when I open the `index.html` file.

Answer (score 0):

Since I used import statements inside my javacsript files it caused some problems when trying to access them when openning the `index.html`.

I used webpack to solve that issue so I will use the build output. In vercel platform I chose the `OUTPUT DIRECTORY` option as the relevent build output - `dist` in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I found what has helped me when deploying static files is creating another folder inside the root directory. And then put all the files in the newly created folder.